# « En quoi/comment/de quelle manière » [des mots entre guillemets] diffère(-t-il/elle) [d'autres mots entre guillemets] : choix et formulation ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, genre, formulation, interrogative

> *En quoi* « cultivé en intérieur » diffère de « …à l'intérieur » ?
> *Comment* « cultivé en intérieur » diffère de « …à l'intérieur » ?
> *De quelle manière* « cultivé en intérieur » diffère de « …à l'intérieur » ?

Est-il aussi usuel d'introduire cette [interrogative](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3383) avec *en quoi*, *comment* et *de quelle manière*, y a-t-il une nuance de sens, et peut-on se passer du pronom suivant le verbe *différer* et référant à « cultivé en intérieur » et quel serait-il ?

Comment: *En quoi « cultivé en intérieur » diffère-t-il de « …à l'intérieur » ?*

Comment: @jlliagre Tu dis donc que _en quoi_ est le plus usuel des trois, que je ne pouvais me passer du pronom suivant le verbe, et que ce qu'on cite, c'est un truc neutre à moins de préciser donc c'est le pronom masculin ? Aurait-on été choqué par _elle_ ?

Comment: _En quoi l'expression « cultivé en intérieur » diffère-t-elle de « …à l'intérieur »_
Mais effectivement, « en quoi » est plus usuel, et l'absence de pronom sonne étrangement.